# I want to get related searches or keywords

Tags: analysis, keyword

How can I use php to categorise different keywords together for example to consider shoes, boots, nike, etc in the similar categories.

Any code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*(Warning: a fundamentalist approach)* Look at MIT Reality Commons [[0](http://realitycommons.media.mit.edu/realitymining2.html)] and OpenCyc [[1](https://github.com/asanchez75/opencyc)], [[2](http://slor.sourceforge.net/e_ocyc.htm)]. These are two open databases of common sense. Make several searches by categories you're interested in. You'll get some related terms for each category. Put it in a fast database of your liking, and you're set.

Also, various SEO people like to create clouds of related keywords in `meta` tags of relevant pages. Take a look at source of several such pages, extract and filter keywords.

Comment: Both links are dead in 2021

Comment: @alexb: Thank you; hopefully fixed.